# How to send HTTP Headers and url variables via CURL to Paypal in a 'RequestPermissions' operation?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, http-headers

As the title suggest I am trying to make a CURL call to Paypal, but I have come across an error that I believe has to do with the way I am sending my headers via CURL.

In the code example below I am declaring to two arrays with the values Paypal requires to process the request. `$headers` will be used in the CURL request as the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, and `$URLvariable` will be concatenated with `$url` and be used as the `CURLOPT_URL`.

Code Example:

```
$headers = array(
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID : MYSSANDBOXUSERID',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD : MYSSANDBOXPASSWORD',
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE : MYSSANDBOXUSERSIGNATURE',
    'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT : JSON',
    'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT : JSON',
    'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID : APP-80W284485P519543T'
);

$URLvariable = array (
        'scope' => 'EXPRESS_CHECKOUT',
        'callback' => 'http://vendorpages.info/success.html', 
        'requestEnvelope' =>  '{"errorLanguage":"en_US"}',
);

foreach ( $URLvariable as $key => $value ) {
    $URLvariable .= '&' . $key . '=' . urlencode ( $value );
}

$url = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions?" . ltrim ( $URLvariable, '&' );

$curl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
$result = curl_exec ( $curl );
curl_close ( $curl );
$result = urldecode ( $result );
$result = explode ( '=',$result );

print_r ($result);
```

*Please note I have replaced my Paypal sandbox credentials on purpose.

The output of which is:

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: AkamaiGHost Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 177 Expires: Sat, 08 Feb 2014 09:47:53 GMT Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2014 09:47:53 GMT Connection: close An error occurred while processing your request.

Reference #166.c60300cc.1391852873.2b18ca34 )
```

Any constructive help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you've got JSON set in your headers, but you're not passing JSON data.  You're just using URL parameters like an NVP request.  You need to pass the actual JSON (or XML) request into the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option in your CURL.

What you're doing is causing your endpoint URL to be incorrect, which is why you're getting the error you're getting.  The $url that you're passing in CURL should just be:

https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions

Then, again, the actual request body would go in the POSTFIELDS option.  I've always used XML, so here's what my headers look like.

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ****
    [1] => X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ****
    [2] => X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ****
    [3] => X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SUBJECT: 
    [4] => X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-VERSION: 109.0
    [5] => X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: XML
    [6] => X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: XML
    [7] => X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T
    [8] => X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-ID: 
    [9] => X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 192.168.1.115
    [10] => X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS: developer@email.com
)
```

The function that I'm using to process my curl request is:

```
function CURLRequest($Request = "", $APIName = "", $APIOperation = "")
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this -> EndPointURL . $APIName . '/' . $APIOperation);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Request);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this -> BuildHeaders(false));

        if($this -> APIMode == 'Certificate')
        {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this -> PathToCertKeyPEM);
        }

        $Response = curl_exec($curl);       
        curl_close($curl);
        return $Response;
    }
```

In that example, $Request was sent as...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RequestPermissionsRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  </requestEnvelope>
  <scope xmlns="">EXPRESS_CHECKOUT</scope>
  <callback xmlns="">http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.4/samples/RequestPermissions-Callback.php</callback>
</RequestPermissionsRequest>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using XML as well.

Comment: I see you are familiar with Paypal... uhm, can I suggest if you are ever in a position of power with them please recommend a complete overhaul of there developer section/help content/guides... I found it to be all over the place...

Comment: Heh, they just did that when they launched the new developer.paypal.com a few months ago.  They just have a whole bunch of different ways to integrate their stuff so it can be a little overwhelming if you're new to their platform.

Comment: Indeed! I noticed that.

Comment: Hopefully this will catch your attention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650307/generating-signatures-for-the-authentication-header-in-php-paypal  I'de greatly appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.